# Why are all my commits in SourceTree in one straight line?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I recently started using Git and SourceTree for a project I'm working on. I have worked with Git a little bit before in a previous job, in which case I used Fork. Someone else then set everything up for me. The structure was a typical git flow structure, with master, develop and feature branches. I don't remember if there was a git flow tool helping out, or that the branches were simply manually set up like this, for lack of a better description.

When I started my recent project, I was aware of the structure described above, but not of the existence of the Git-Flow tool in SourceTree, so I didn't use it. I also didn't create a develop branch, but I'm not sure if that is part of the problem. My graph in SourceTree is now a straight line, despite having worked on a different branch from main. This is not what I expected. Maybe I'm doing it wrong or maybe I understand it wrong, it would be great if someone could explain it to me.

My process was as follows:
I added my files to the repository, so that was the start of the 'main' branch (right?). I then created a branch, did some work and made some commits, before merging it back onto 'main'. The 'main' tag stayed with that first commit until I merged, then both the 'main' tag and the branch tag moved to that latest commit.

I've created a very simple, quick drawing which illustrates what I mean. Left is what I expected, right is what I got.

[image: drawing]

I hope someone can clarify for me. Is this because nothing changed on 'main' while I worked on the branch? Would this look different when I use the Git-flow tool in SourceTree? What happens if I turn on the Git-flow tool now?

Comment: Probably you are squash-merging?

Comment: Well.... Actually, the question would be: when you "merge", do you get all the original commits in the resulting branch.... or a single commit that contains the whole thing?

Comment: And so.... here's a brief explanation if you get all the original commits: git is _lazy_.... it will (by default) avoid doing a merge if there's no need to. So, if you create a feature branch, 10 commits, then go back to main (which hasn't moved) and ask to merge the feature branch, given that main hasn't moved, then branches haven't diverged and git will simply run a _fast-forward_ to the tip of the branch you are merging and that's it. If main had moved, then git is _forced_ to do a real merge.

Comment: If no new commits were added to `main` while you were working on your branch, then merging will effectively just make `main` point at the same commit as the branch. That's called a fast-forward merge (it doesn't have to "merge" anything because only one of the two things changed, therefore the result of the "merge" is literally the same as the thing that changed).

Comment: @eftshift0 thank you for your explanation. I read something about the fast-forward earlier, so in SourceTree I went to Tools > Options > Git and I ticked 'Do not fast-forward when merging, always create commit'. But I only did this after I merged. Will this give me the result I want in the future?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I was afraid of that. It makes sense, yet I'd prefer to see the graph as I described it because it helps me see my workflow. Would git-flow help with this?

Comment: Most tools can be configured to disable fast-forward merges. Personally I prefer FF merges over all other options, but I understand that it's subjective. If you use `git merge` directly then simply passing `--no-ff` will disable fast-forward merges. That will provide the desired result in the future but obviously doesn't influence the past.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If you add an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Perhaps you know the answer by now, but the answer to: "But I only did this after I merged. Will this give me the result I want in the future?" is yes, future merges will be performed with the `--no-ff` option to force a merge commit. Side note, I'm not sure how that setting works in SourceTree, but if it were me, I might prefer to have that merge commit when I'm merging into `main`, but not for other branches. For example, I would prefer the possible fast-forward when merging one feature branch into another. (But I only use the command line for merges so I just pick the option I want.)